# MATLAB - passing parameters to pdist custom distance function

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, distance, pdist

I've implemented a custom distance function for k-medoids algorithm in Matlab, following the directions found in [pdist](http://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html).

Basically it compares two vectors, say `A` and `B` (which can also have different lengths) and checks if their elements "co-occur with tolerance": `A(i)` and `B(j)` co-occur with tolerance `tol` if

```
abs( A(i) - B(j) ) <= tol
```

Without going into details, the distance is large if there are few "co-occurrences with tolerance".

Everything works as I expect if I define `tol` as a constant inside the function, but now I would like to pass it as a parameter whenever I call k-medoids. pdist documentation does not mention this possibility:

> A distance function specified using @: 
>   D = pdist(X,@distfun).
>   A distance function must be of form
>   d2 = distfun(XI,XJ),
>   taking as arguments a 1-by-n vector XI, corresponding to a single row of X, and an m2-by-n matrix XJ, corresponding to multiple rows of X. distfun must accept a matrix XJ with an arbitrary number of rows. distfun must return an m2-by-1 vector of distances d2, whose kth element is the distance between XI and XJ(k,:).

So, is it possible to pass parameters in some way to a custom distance function in Matlab? If not, which alternatives should I consider?

Comment: Why not just `abs(bsxfun(@minus, A(:), B(:).')) <= tol`? What's the exact result you want?

Comment: I call k-medoids as `[idx, C] = kmedoids(data,2,'Distance',@custom_distance);`. I would like to pass to `custom_distance` a value for `tol`. (the distance itself works, I used `ismembertol`). For now, I'm just specifying `tol` as a constant inside `custom_distance`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your general question, yes you can pass custom parameters to your custom distance function. You can define distfun in this way

```
a = 1; % Variable you want to pass to your function
distanceFunction = @(xi, xj)yourCustomDistanceFunction(xi, xj, a)
```

`yourCustomDistanceFunction` should accept the default parameters as the first two inputs and then the last input is your own variable (that isn't passed by `pdist`).

Then provide it to `pdist` in the following way

```
pdist(X, distanceFunction)
```